# android customViews in kotlin - is it ok to initialize in the init block?

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I am so confused why no one uses the init block in a android custom view to initialize and inflate the view. lets take an example of how i do this:

```
class MyCompoundView : ConstraintLayout {
    constructor(p0: Context) : super(p0)
    constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?) : super(p0, p1)
    constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?, p2: Int) : super(p0, p1, p2)

    init {
        inflate(context, R.layout.my_view_container, this)
//etc
    }

}
```

is there anything wrong with this as opposed to what i see all over the internet:

```
class MyCompoundView : ConstraintLayout {
    constructor(p0: Context) : super(p0){initialize()}

    constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?) : super(p0, p1){initialize()}
    constructor(p0: Context, p1: AttributeSet?, p2: Int) : super(p0, p1, p2){initialize()}

 private fun initialize() {
        inflate(context, R.layout.ride_hail_otp_container, this)

    }

  }
```

ps. i do not favor jvmOverload in customViews so no need to mention that. just want to know about init block vs calling it in each constructor.  i see no one doing it online and i wonder why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's totally fine, I my self used this approach many times and ain't facing any problems.

- one of the examples I'm currently working with :

  ```
  class MaterialSearchBar (context: Context, val attributeSet: AttributeSet) : Toolbar(context, attributeSet) {
      init {
      inflate(context, R.layout.material_search_toolbar, this)
      updateUi()
      requestFocus()
      setUpListeners()
      }

  //...

  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with inflating the view in the `init` block (I do it in my custom views) just like there is nothing wrong with `@JvmOVerloads`.

Comment: prefer not to use jvmOverLoad - https://blog.q42.nl/the-danger-of-assumptions-kotlin-with-android-custom-views-adb79bf2da45?gi=60df557ce4bd